# Simple closed set proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I want to show that $$\{ x: x_1 +x _2 = 1, x_1, x_2 \geq 0\}$$

is closed.

Let $(x_1^*, x_2^*)$ be limit points of the set with $(x_1^{(k)},x_2^{(k)})\rightarrow (x_1^*, x_2^*)$ where the $(x_1^{(k)},x_2^{(k)})$ belong to the set.

Then:

$$x_1^*+ x_2^* = \lim x_1^{(k)} + \lim x_2^{(k)} = \lim (x_1^{(k)} +x_2^{(k)}) = \lim 1 = 1$$

Also, since the sequence is in the set, each component must be nonnegative, so the components of the limit are nonnegative.

Comment: I think that $x_1+x_1$ in your question must be replaced by $x_1+x_2$. Is $x=(x_1,x_2)$ here? The components are not positive, but are nonnegative. $x_1^{k}$ can easily be read as a power. Your idea is okay.

Comment: Typo, yes, $x_1 + x_2 = 1$. Yes $x = (x_1, x_2)$. My idea is Okay? How do i improve it?

Comment: Right, nonegative

Comment: This way you prove that every limitpoint of the set belongs to the set, which means exactly that the set is closed.

Comment: You said "okay" but is it wrong?

Comment: No it is not wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f:\left[0,1\right]^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)\mapsto x_{1}+x_{2}$.
Then your set is the preimage of closed set $\left\{ 1\right\} $
under continuous $f$ . So it must be closed in $\left[0,1\right]^{2}$ wich is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So it is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ too.

Also you could take $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)\mapsto x_{1}+x_{2}$.
Then your set is the intersection of closed set $\left[0,1\right]^{2}\subset\mathbb R^2$
and the preimage of closed set $\left\{ 1\right\} $ under continuous $f$. This is suggested in the answer of lhf.

Comment: "of closed set $\{ 1 \}$ ", sorry this sentence didn't make sense to me.

Comment: Also, it doesn't take everything in the unit square.

Comment: If $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with its usual topology then every subset
of $\mathbb{R}$ that is a singleton (e.g. $\left\{ 1\right\} $)
is a closed set. Does that makes sense to you?

Comment: Are you talking about the image, and not the premimage? Because the image is always the singleton $\{ 1 \}$. Or are you saying because the image is closed, under continuity, the image must also be closed?

Comment: I start with set $\{1\}$. It is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$. Then the preimage of that set under $f$ ( that is by definition the set $\left\{ \left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)\in\left[0,1\right]^{2}\mid f\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)=1\right\} $) must be closed as well. This because $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Oh that's what you mean. Okay

Answer (score 1):

The set is the inverse image of a closed set by a continuous function intersected with another closed set, hence it is closed.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be useful to remember that the intersection of closed set is closed. The three sets $\{x_1+x_2=1\}$,  $\{x_1\geq 0\}$, $\{x_2\geq0\}$ are obviously closed, are they?

Comment: Thanks, but I already lost so many marks in my assignment for these type of answers that I don't want to lose more….

Comment: You mean the “obviously close” statement? Well if it is for an exam, you'd better write something like “Suppose $x_1 <0$... if we take $\varepsilon >0$ very little, then... hence...” :-P

Comment: Isn't that more work than what I have…?

Comment: Well, I guess it really depends on (a) your taste (b) what kind of answer is requested in your assignment. What you are doing in your (correct) proof is essantially what is synthetized in lhf's answer or in mine, when I naively say that it's obvious that such sets are closed. The three ways are equivalent.